# How to add a div in jquery even if you have just used the .remove() function on it

Tags: jquery, html

Below is my code which I am using to remove a div tag. I also want the script to add the same div tag later once certain conditions are meet. The div has some preloaded content too which I don't want to loose.

$('#wrapper1').remove();

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Cheers,
Vishal

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `.remove()`, use `.hide()` then `.show()` to bring it back again. Once you `.remove()` an element, it's gone forever. If you want to add it back into a different place, you can use `.appendTo()` then `.show()`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to just keep a reference...here though if you have content you likely want to use [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) rather than [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) (which removes all data/events immediately), like this:

```
var wrapper = $('#wrapper1').detach();
```

Then later:

```
$("selector").append(wrapper);
```

The alternative is to just show/hide it if you don't want to move it, it really depends what you're after here.

Comment: here is good writeup on `remvoe() vs detach()` http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1822-Learning-jQuery-1-4-Remove-vs-Detach-.htm

Answer (score 1):

**Don't remove it.**

**Just use**  `$("#wrapper1").hide()` *to hide it.*

**Then** `$("#wrapper1").show()` *to show it when you need it again.*